# npm run scripts in separate file

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, package.json

I have an Angular project that has several libraries, using a plugin Architecture the idea is to be able to build and then serve each plugin in a separate server.

My build:plugins script is getting rather long:

```json
scripts: {
   "build:plugins" : "ng build plugin1 && ng build plugin2 && ng build plugin3 && ng build plugin4 ..."

}
```

you get the idea.

Is there any way to move the `ng build plugin 1...`  to a script file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash.

Since npm scripts are bash, moving them to a separate bash file will do the trick.

Create a file called script.sh, move the command there, and then you do the following on the command line

```
bash script.sh
```